# Figuring out who is the real owner of Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-privacy

Is there any way for anyone at Facebook to determine, who is the real owner of Facebook Page?

I want the create a webpage, where I want to post some true facts about my previous employer, to prevent others from falling into same problems, like I did. There will be absolutely no lies, just the pure facts (but verifiable only, once you're employed, not before, and that is the purpose of the page). But even so, I want to avoid any problems did by my former employer. And in the same time, I don't want to violate Facebook's policy and registering another (fake) account for setting up that page.

Is there *any* way for my former employer or anyone to find out, who had actually created (and is managing) particular Facebok Page? Or this kind of details are available only to Facebook stuff and would be revealed only upon eventual court case?

Comment: @AlE. Well, I think that my question isn't a duplicate or at least is an in-direct duplicate. I'm asking, if this is possible (security reasons), why linked question is asking, how to do this (technical issues). But, OK, of others find this duplicate, then sorry for repeating and go ahead, close this one.

Comment: Notice it says "possible duplicate"? If a case can be made that they're related and not duplicates, this question will remain open. (And even if it is closed as a duplicate, it could always be re-opened.) I just feel it's a duplicate because the answer in both cases is the same: The owner of a page cannot be known unless the page owner sets it to be seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no guarantees:   Facebook's current policy is that the page-creator and current administrators' are not shown to people - but they could change their rules at any time.